# PHP: Database structure for user based networking

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, networking

Some basics:
I am using a user authenticated login to an admin system that allows users to add customers, and an array of info about customers, including geo-location information for use with GMap API. My goal is to allow users to add each other for networking purposes in regards to their customer clientele. I am wondering what the best approach at building the database/table structure should be.

At the moment, I have a database called `pbud1` with a `users` table and a `customers` table. For networking, my idea is to use the `users` unique id-> `uid` as an identifier for their network. Then add a table when a network is instantiated by the user, naming the table `network_`+`the id from their 'users' table`, ex: `network_uid` where `pbud1`.`network_uid` = `pbud1`.`users`.`uid`. So if the user has an id of 6 it would be `network_6`. Then within the new table `"network_6"`, place relevant information on each row about each user that is added to that users network, ie; nid(key/ai) net_user_id(uid), geo_location, business, name, etc...

Goal: Allow each user within their parent network to access that specific user.parent customers information. Suggest users to user.parent due to geo_location of customer base between related users.

Honestly the semantics are not so important here as the structure and build of the DB table relationship in regards to the ability for networked users to access each others `customers` information.

Any assistance on approach would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The approach where a new table is generated for every network won't scale up, what queries would you like to do on this database? It's important to think of the way of you want to query your data before you design the actual structure. And if your system will allow it you could take a look of graph databases for example like [neo4j](https://neo4j.com/) these databases are specially designed for networks.

Comment: I think you would be better of just using a network_uid column in each table, instead of creating a new table, instead of doing this: 
"SELECT * FROM network_6" you would do something like
"SELECT * FROM networks WHERE network_uid = 6"